# PHP regular expression match gives error

Tags: php, eregi

Trying to check the string for pattern.

```
$variable = '[text]';

if (eregi("/(\[(.*?)\])/", $variable)) {}
```

This code gives error `eregi() [function.eregi]: REG_BADRPT`

**What is the solution for this?**

Comment: Why are you using eregi? From the manual: *This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0. Relying on this feature is highly discouraged.* http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eregi.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you're using a preg style expression in eregi. You don't need the perl style delimiters.

However, as Mark Byers comments, using preg_match is future proof.

```
<?php
$variable = '[text]';

if (preg_match("/(\[(.*?)\])/", $variable)) {
    echo 'ok';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify, pearl style delimeters are the two slashes. This is what ereg syntax looks like:

```
<?php
$str = 'abc';
if (ereg('a', $str))
{
  echo 'match found'; // match found
}
?>
```

I didn't use a regular expression, as you normally would, just to keep things simple.

I also want to mention that there are multibyte ereg functions that are still valid, for example [mb_ereg](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-ereg.php).